# C# Mono Console.ReadLine quitting

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono

I am building an application with MONO (C#) on linux mint 14 but i have some issues. I have enabled external console in the options and while debugging it's working quite well but after deploying ( openning the .exe in debug folder) the application quits immediately after the Console.ReadLine(); Any ideas guys ?

```
public static void InitializeUI() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("On the bottom line enter the command \"START\" followed by a space and a number representing on how many hours to check for new posts. You can always stop the execution with Ctrl+C \r\n \r\nExample : START 6");
            ParseCMD();
            Console.ReadLine ();
        }
        private static void ParseCMD()
        {
            string cmd = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] commands = cmd.Trim().Split(new string[] {" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int delay = 0;
            if (commands[0].ToLower() == "start" && int.TryParse(commands[1],out delay))
            {
                MainLogic.StartLogic(delay);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong command");
                ParseCMD();
            }
        }
```

quits after the

```
string cmd = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Could you, please, add some code example of what you are doing?

Comment: wrap your method with try catch block and print the exception and again put console read line. this may be due to a exception, you need to find exact exception before move on..

Comment: Also note that if the user just presses `<return>` without entering any data, the `commands[]` array will be empty and the `commands[0].ToLower()` will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("On the bottom line enter the command \"START\" followed by a space and a number representing on how many hours to check for new posts. You can always stop the execution with Ctrl+C \r\n \r\nExample : START 6");


        if(!ParseCMD(readKeey()))
        {
            ParseCMD(readKeey());
        }

    }private static string readKeey()
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
        Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;

        string temp="";
        do
        {
            cki = Console.ReadKey();
            temp=temp+cki.KeyChar;

        } while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
        return temp;
    }

    private static bool ParseCMD(string text)
    {
        try{
            string cmd = text;
            string[] commands = cmd.Trim().Split(new string[] {" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int delay = 0;
            if (commands[0].ToLower() == "start" && int.TryParse(commands[1],out delay))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Right command you enter:" + commands[0] + commands[1]);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong command");

                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ex.Message:"+ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}}
```

I guess it is nothing about Mono, could you please try Console.ReadKey() instead.